# exception installing leksah

Tags: haskell, leksah

Installing leksah with sudo cabal install leksah --global
I got

7 of 12] Compiling Text.PrinterParser ( src/Text/PrinterParser.hs,                      dist/build/Text/PrinterParser.o )

src/Text/PrinterParser.hs:230:42: Not in scope: `catch'
Failed to install ltk-0.8.0.6

This makes impossible to continue the installation. 
It looks to me a bug, but i can be wrong.

note that i use ghc 7.6.3
and ghc-pkg list  gives back:

```
    Cabal-1.16.0
    GLURaw-1.3.0.0
    GLUT-2.4.0.0
    HTTP-4000.2.8
    HUnit-1.2.5.2
    OpenGL-2.8.0.0
    OpenGLRaw-1.3.0.0
    QuickCheck-2.6
    array-0.4.0.1
    async-2.0.1.4
    attoparsec-0.10.4.0
    base-4.6.0.1
    bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
    binary-0.5.1.1
    binary-shared-0.8.3
    bytestring-0.10.0.2
    cairo-0.12.4
    case-insensitive-1.0.0.1
    cgi-3001.1.7.5
    containers-0.5.0.0
    deepseq-1.3.0.1
    directory-1.2.0.1
    fgl-5.4.2.4
    filepath-1.3.0.1
    ghc-7.6.3
    ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
    ghc-prim-0.3.0.0
    gio-0.12.4
    glade-0.12.1
    glib-0.12.4
    gtk-0.12.4
    gtksourceview2-0.12.3.1
    haddock-2.13.2.1
    hashable-1.1.2.5
    haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
    haskell-src-1.0.1.5
    haskell2010-1.1.1.0
    haskell98-2.0.0.2
    hoopl-3.9.0.0
    hpc-0.6.0.0
    hslogger-1.2.1
    html-1.0.1.2
    integer-gmp-0.5.0.0
    mtl-2.1.2
    network-2.4.1.2
    old-locale-1.0.0.5
    old-time-1.1.0.1
    pango-0.12.4
    parallel-3.2.0.3
    parsec-3.1.3
    pretty-1.1.1.0
    primitive-0.5.0.1
    process-1.1.0.2
    random-1.0.1.1
    regex-base-0.93.2
    regex-compat-0.95.1
    regex-posix-0.95.2
    regex-tdfa-1.1.8
    rts-1.0
    split-0.2.2
    stm-2.4.2
    syb-0.4.0
    template-haskell-2.8.0.0
    text-0.11.3.1
    time-1.4.0.1
    transformers-0.3.0.0
    unix-2.6.0.1
    unordered-containers-0.2.3.0
    utf8-string-0.3.7
    vector-0.10.0.1
    xhtml-3000.2.1
    zlib-0.5.4.1
    /home/blackbird014/.ghc/i386-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
    binary-shared-0.8.3
    ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
    haddock-2.13.2.1
    hslogger-1.2.1
    regex-tdfa-1.1.8
    utf8-string-0.3.7
```

Thanx in advance for ideas (perhaps i am doing something wrong. ATM I am wondering if I need to install an older ghc)

Comment: Here's an idea: use [SublimeHaskell](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell) instead. Leksah really isn't a preferred choice of Haskellers.

Comment: I think you need to do a `cabal update`. It looks like the latest `leksah` on hackage depends on `ltk >= 0.12.1.0`, and cabal was trying to build ltk-0.8.0.6. If I'm correct, that would mean you haven't done an `update` since september 2010, in which case: welcome to the future :)

Comment: i did. And it is a new installation.

Comment: Well I did the cabal update: perhaps I am too much in the future now :-).... And it is a new installation. At the end I have installed ltk downloading the right version and building it (also this has some problems ... this time cabal was too update ). I found easier to use the eclipse plugin. But I want to compare some IDE to choose the one which better fits my needs.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/leksah/issues/detail?id=271

Comment: @Nikita Volkov SublimeHaskell is commerical only if you pay 70 bucks . I tried to install the latest dev build but it is only for payed customers. Also SublimeHaskell is written in python. So there are servere draw backs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I have realized that the question has no answers but we have come to an acceptable reply in the  comments.... 
I could only solve the problem by downloading the ltk version needed, ltk-0.8.0.6 and building it from sources. If you have the same problem you can proceed like this.